# Getting data in variable if value is set

Tags: php, logic

I have 3 variable mat , follow , not 
only one can have value at a time what I want if any of the variables has value it should be updated in msg

this is my logic

```
<?php     
    $mat = $this->input->post('mater_mesaage') ;
    $folow = $this->input->post('follow_message') ;
    $not = $this->input->post('not_inst_comment') ;     
    if (isset($mat)){
        echo "Mat";
        $msg = $mat  ;
    } 
    if (isset($folow )) {
        echo "folow" ;
       $msg = $folow ;
    }
    if (isset($not)){
        echo "not" ;
        $msg = $not ;
    }
    echo $msg ;
?>
```

Comment: **==** is used for comparison, you must use **=** for assign a value

Comment: still its not working

Answer (score 1):

please replace `==` with `=`

```
<?php     
    $mat = $this->input->post('mater_mesaage') ;
    $folow = $this->input->post('follow_message') ;
    $not = $this->input->post('not_inst_comment') ;     
    if (isset($mat)){
        echo "Mat" ;
        $msg = $mat  ;
    } 
    if (isset($folow )) {
        echo "folow" ;
        $msg = $folow ;
    }
    if (isset($not)){
        echo "not" ;
        $msg = $not ;
    }
    echo $msg ;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One value at a time so u should have to use `elseif` so here you go:

```
<?php     
    $mat = $this->input->post('mater_mesaage') ;
    $folow = $this->input->post('follow_message') ;
    $not = $this->input->post('not_inst_comment') ;     
    if (isset($mat)){
        echo "Mat";
        $msg == $mat;
    }elseif (isset($folow )) {
        echo "folow";
       $msg == $folow;
    }else{
        echo "not";
        $msg == $not;
    }
    echo $msg;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php     
    $mat = $this->input->post('mater_mesaage');
    $folow = $this->input->post('follow_message');
    $not = $this->input->post('not_inst_comment');     
    if ($mat != '' || $folow != '' || $not != '') {
        $msg = ($mat != '') ? $mat : (($folow != '') ? $follow : $not);
    }
?>
```

Comment: the issue here is if $mat has value it will be printed but if $follow or $not has value it is not printing
Your code also has the same issue